# Access Music and Documents Java Android

Tags: java, android, file, documents

I'm currently working on an Android app that will allow users to chat and transfer files among each other. I figured out how to access the photo library in my phone, now I want to access the Music and Documents.
This is the piece of code I used to access photos:

```
photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

Is there a similar way to access the Music and Documents?

Thank you

Comment: use `photoPickerIntent.setType("*/*");`

Answer (score 0):

Check this -

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

Hope it will help u..